# Moving in TeXstudio on a Mac

Tags: texstudio, mac

is there a way to make TeXstudio's shortcuts behave as one would expect on OS X? In particular, Command+Left usually moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, but in TeXstudio it takes me left a word. Similarly, Alt-Left usually moves the cursor a word to the left, but in TeXstudio it moves the cursor to the previous edit location.

Comment: Does [this](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION05) solve the problem? The other solution in a general cases is to overwrite the shortcuts from OS X settings (you can even assign shortcuts for those commands that don't have one by default). P.S. I also agree, texstudio has some really annoying shortcuts on OS X.

Comment: You have it as an answer!

Comment: Note: From the next version on (2.7.2) TeXstudio will provide more native shortcuts on OSX by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying TeXstudio shortcuts are done from `Configur->Shortcuts` menu. [**Here**](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION05) you can find information in details:

[image]

If there is a shortcut (not only for this case, but in general) that you can't modify or a command has no shortcut assigned to, you can use [OS X settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13916) to solve the problem.